# Bing API integration for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am not able to figure out where the problem is. im trying to integrate bing search api, i referenced the similar question that was answered here. my code is pretty much the same. but im not able to get the results. the exceptions i am getting are:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Http.WebException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled
>   before a managed/native boundary An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Http.WebException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceTransportException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WP80.DLL

please help me out....

```
using Bing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using System.Net;


//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace MyApp
{
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
    }

    void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main();


    }





    // Bing Search API code sample that demonstrates the News service operation.
    // Replace this value with your account key.
    //private const string AccountKey = "38d768UB4hTJgOhVpQGBIsqn5tNXi5PDlAWgnIAbjnY=";

    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            MakeRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string innerMessage =
            (ex.InnerException != null) ?
            ex.InnerException.Message : String.Empty;
            string str = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", ex.Message, innerMessage);
            NewText.Text = str;
        }
    }
    public void MakeRequest()
    {
        const string AccountKey = "1U2M99wYcQb8gukg3Qk96uneDEZKx8GVDNeebXcabj4";

        // This is the query expression.
        string query = "rihanna";

        // Create a Bing container.
        string rootUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
        var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUrl));

        // The market to use.
        //string market = "en-us";

        // Get news for science and technology.
        //string newsCat = "rt_ScienceAndTechnology";

        // Configure bingContainer to use your credentials.
        bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AccountKey, AccountKey);

        // Build the query, limiting to 10 results.
        var newsQuery =
        bingContainer.News(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        //newsQuery = newsQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);

        // Run the query and display the results.
        //var newsResults = newsQuery.Execute();

        try
        {
            newsQuery.BeginExecute(_onNewsQueryComplete, newsQuery);
        }
        catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
       "An error occurred during query execution.", ex);
        }
    }



    public void _onNewsQueryComplete(IAsyncResult newsResults)
    {

        DataServiceQuery<Bing.NewsResult> quer = newsResults.AsyncState as 
        DataServiceQuery<Bing.NewsResult>;




        var sanjay = new List<string>();

        foreach (var result in quer.EndExecute(newsResults))
        {
            sanjay.Add(
             result.Source);


        }

        NewText.Text += sanjay + "/n";
        //newmeth(j,sanjay);

    }









}


}
```

Comment: ["I wrote this program for my assignment and it doesn't work."](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have tried so many times to integrate bing API with WP8 and It never worked and I had to create a web API project to deal with the requests instead of creating requests from WP8 project